# How do I query user input?

Tags: java, android, android-room

I'm learning `SQL` and `Room`. I have successfully queried all data in `Room`:

```
@Query( "SELECT * FROM my_table" )
LiveData<List<MyRoomEntity>>getAllData();
```

I have also specified the search to the `name` column:

```
@Query( "SELECT id, name FROM my_table" )
LiveData<List<MyRoomEntity>>getAllNames();
```

Next step is to query user input. Let's say the user wants to search the database for Bob. What does that look like as a query? Obviously the query should be dynamic and query `userInput` and not specifically Bob ;)

I have searched for a solution to this, but I'm new to `Room` and `SQL` so I think I need a bit help here :)

Comment: Read up about the SQL- WHERE clause and String concatenation. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp

Comment: Room assumes you have basic knowledge about SQL. I recommend reading about SQL first. Once you've done that visit this link : https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data

Comment: @Query( "SELECT id, name FROM my_table where name= "+userIput )

Answer (score 1):

Use `:input` and make sure to include a parameter, like this:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE name = :input" )
LiveData<List<MyRoomEntity>>getUserInputName(String input);
```

Then in the `Repository`:

```
public LiveData<List<MyRoomEntity>> getUserInputName(String inputName) {
    return this.roomDao.getUserInputName(inputName);
}
```

And in the `ViewModel`:

```
public void getUserInputName(String inputName) {
    repository.getUserInputName(inputName).observe( mOwner, new android.arch.lifecycle.Observer<List<MyRoomEntity>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable List<MyRoomEntity> myRoomEntities) {
            if(myRoomEntities != null) {
                for(MyRoomEntity item: myRoomEntities) {
                    Log.d("TAG ROOM ", "Input Name: " + item.toString());
                }
            }
        }
    } );
}
```

Just pass the parameter and argument. And finally, when you call the method in `MainActivity()`:

```
private String input = "Joe";
myViewModel.getUserInputName(input);
```